# firebase functions endpoint cold starts

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase REST endpoint.  I am getting a lot of NULL returns especially at startup.  Looking through other issues, I think it is a Coldstart.  I believe the issue is that I am using callbacks which is returning before firebase has a chance to return a dataset.  I read a comment about callabcks from @puf - frank-van-puffelen
sugesting a Cold Start. So I'm trying to re-write as a promise.  This code works, usually, but still get the cold start NULL data sets.  How would I do this as a promise?

```js
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//=================================================================================================
//  KeysFromAccountGet01
//=================================================================================================
// This function is not working correctly because it often returns a NULL set. probably 
// because I am using callbacks instead of promises, and the callback returns before firebase 
// can return a query.  Usually it works.
// But I am fairly sure that I should be using PROMICES so as to wait for the data to arrive.
// that said, I can not figure out how to do a promise.  Everythign I have tried returns nothing.
// some sugestions on how to do promises for this would be appreciated. 
//curl 'https://us-central1-test.cloudfunctions.net/KeysFromAccountGet01?account=dporras8'
//curl 'https://us-central1-test.cloudfunctions.net/KeysFromAccountGet01?account='
//firebase deploy --only functions:KeysFromAccountGet01
exports.KeysFromAccountGet01 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
  var arr =[];
  arr.push("1====+++starting");
  arr.push("acount = "+ req.query.account);
 admin.database().ref('/newacctok/'+req.query.account+'/tok3/').on('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(miniSnapShot){
        var tt = miniSnapShot.val();
             var json = ({ 
                    "key":miniSnapShot.key,
                    "account":req.query.account,
                     "uuid":tt.uuid,
                     "ts2":tt.ts2,
                     "token":tt.token
             }); 
       arr.push(json);
 })
    .then(res.status(200).send(arr));
});

//===================================
```

Comment: Promises won't make any difference to the behavior. They just make the code easier to read when you have multiple nested loads. What problem do you have when you move the `send(...)` into the callback?

Comment: And definitely do what Bob says: use a `once()`. There is no use for a continuous listener in a HTTP function.

Comment: Did did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure these changes will help with your Null returns.  Note that I changed `on()`, which leaves the listener attached, to `once()`. Also, I've seen answers from Frank van Puffelen cautioning against performing asynchronous processing in HTTPS request functions. I'll try to find his answers/comments and add them.

```
exports.KeysFromAccountGet01 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var arr =[];
  arr.push("1====+++starting");
  arr.push("acount = "+ req.query.account);
  // note change from on() to once()
  admin.database().ref('/newacctok/'+req.query.account+'/tok3/').once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(miniSnapShot => {
        var tt = miniSnapShot.val();
        var json = ({
          "key":miniSnapShot.key,
          "account":req.query.account,
          "uuid":tt.uuid,
          "ts2":tt.ts2,
          "token":tt.token
        });
        arr.push(json);
      });
      res.status(200).send(arr)
    });
});
```